# G-Code - Decrypting Z-Code to G-code

Tags: file-format, g-code

I have a Zortrax m200 3d printer which you may/ may not be familiar with. It is closed source, and uses its own proprietary software to produce Z-code files which should in principal be almost identical to G-code.

My curiosity has kicked in and I'm wondering whether there is a way to decrypt a Z-code file or convert a g-code file to z-code. How would one go about investigating this?

Here is a z-code file:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByYqoSxe29qtS05UZlpDclBZNWs/view?usp=sharing][1]

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a programming question. I'd guess you would get better answer on a 3D printer related forum or Q/A site. [This one](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) comes to mind, don't know why :P.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about 3D printing than programming.

Comment: This in fact is a coding question. Said files contain the 3d printer's tool path, expressed in coordinates. OP is looking for a transpiler (or a way to write one) from a wide-spread but unfortunately proprietary encryption of this data (zcode) to the commonly used and open source friendly gcode, that is industry standard here. Valid question at the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible to do it. You can find a good tool (with source code) here: https://github.com/bonafid3/zcode2gcode
to convert ZCode to GCode.